# Roo doesn't update class-files anymore

Tags: java, spring, spring-roo

After working for weeks on a Roo Project mine stopped to update the .class-files inside the directory:

> Project\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\classes\com\company
>
> and
>
> Project\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\classes\com\company\web

When I deploy with STS on the local Tomcat it used the new class-files but `perform package` command used the old one from the locations mentioned above.

Once I deployed the war-file to a remote server I got silly errors.
It took me like one workday to figure out what is going wrong.

How can I make Roo update the .class-files again? I tried `poll now` but it finishes within one second without any results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried doing a `perform clean` from within the roo shell?  This should remove the target folder and rebuild all your class files.

Comment: Yes I did. The problem is that it doesn't regenerate the .class-files inside the project-folder as described above. When deploying to the local Tomcat inside STS it magically has all the correct class-files.

Comment: I've never had this problem with the roo projects I've worked on have you tried the commandline shell vs the STS view?  If it persists it may be worth pulling in the code in STS and removing the dev dependency on roo.